# Undefined variable passing data using service

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, service, controller

I have declared my app and have one controller (for demonstration purposes):

```
    var module = angular.module("app", [])


    module.controller("modalCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope, dataService) {


    $scope.printEntity = function () {
         console.log(dataService.getEntityArray());
    }

}]);
```

And a service:

```
module.factory("dataService", function () {

var entityArrayService = [1,2];

return {

    getEntityArray: function () {
        return entityArrayService;
    }

};

});
```

When I call `$scope.printEntity` from my view, I'm always told `dataService.getEntityArray()` is undefined.

I've loaded the service as a dependency and declared my entityArrayService array outside of my return statement.   I've looked high and low for an answer but to no avail.  My goal is to share a piece of data between two controllers, but at the minute I can't even use one controller to retrieve data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service isn't loaded as a dependency. Change this line:

```
module.controller("modalCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope, dataService) {
```

to this:

```
module.controller("modalCtrl", ["$scope", "dataService", function ($scope, dataService) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using strict syntax for dependencies declaration. So if you add a parameter to your controller, you must add its declaration too.

```
module.controller("modalCtrl", ["$scope", "dataService", function ($scope, dataService) { 
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't inject `dataService` in your controller. Try with:

```
module.controller("modalCtrl", ["$scope", "dataService", function ($scope, dataService) {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The injection of the service in the controller is missing:

please correct to:

```
...
module.controller("modalCtrl", ["$scope", "dataService", function ($scope, dataService) {
...
```

The other code is correct.